# How do I get a grid to be static in a VBOX using Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, java-8

I've just recently dipped into UI based applications and I'm having trouble getting the generated GridPane to not expand with the window. Ideally, I'd like to be able to hit the small button, have it generate a static grid, and then resize the root stage/scene to compensate for different dungeon sizes. The code below only implements the small button and then draws the grid under it.

This is a screenshot after I hit the small button.(and after I manually resized the window)

[image: This is a screenshot after I hit the small button.(and after I manually resized the window)]

Controller Class

```
    package Window;

    import Data.Area;
    import Model.Grid;
    import Model.TileSet;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
    import javafx.stage.Modality;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Controller {


    public GridPane gridmane;

    public void genSmall(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {

        Grid grid = new Grid(new Area(40, 40));
        grid.getPathfinder().shufflePartitions();
        grid.getPathfinder().fillPartitions();
        grid.getPathfinder().generateHallways();

        importGrid(gridmane, grid);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setOpacity(1);
        stage.setTitle("My New Stage Title");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(gridmane, 340, 400));

        stage.show();
    }


    private void importGrid(GridPane gridPane, Grid grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.getSize().height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.getSize().width; j++) {
                if (grid.getContent()[j + (i * grid.getSize().width)] == TileSet.floorTile) {
                    changeSquare(gridPane, i, j, Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    changeSquare(gridPane, i, j, Color.GRAY);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void changeSquare(GridPane gridPane, int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate, Color color) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rect.setFill(color);
        rect.setWidth(10);
        rect.setHeight(10);
        gridPane.add(rect, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
        }
    }
```

Main Class

```
    package Window;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Main extends Application {

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    int val = 40;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.stage = primaryStage;
        setVal(val);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void setVal(int i) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Dungeon Generator");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 450));
        //primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }


    }
```

FXML File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="258.0" prefWidth="332.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Window.Controller">
   <children>
      <MenuBar>
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#genSmall" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="64.0" text="Small" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="20.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Medium" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="20.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="66.0" text="Large" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="20.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <GridPane fx:id="gridmane" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of those constraints of your `GridPane` rows/columns. For centering you could wrap the grid in a `StackPane` and prevent it's size from growing by using `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE` (=`-Infinity`) as max size constraints.

```xml
<StackPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" >
    <children>
        <GridPane fx:id="gridmane" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" maxWidth="-Infinity" maxHeight="-Infinity" />
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

```
public void genSmall(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {

    Grid grid = new Grid(new Area(40, 40));
    grid.getPathfinder().shufflePartitions();
    grid.getPathfinder().fillPartitions();
    grid.getPathfinder().generateHallways();

    importGrid(gridmane, grid);

    gridmane.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene(); // resize window
}

private void importGrid(GridPane gridPane, Grid grid) {
    gridPane.getChildren().clear(); // remove old children

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.getSize().height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid.getSize().width; j++) {
            if (grid.getContent()[j + (i * grid.getSize().width)] == TileSet.floorTile) {
                changeSquare(gridPane, i, j, Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                changeSquare(gridPane, i, j, Color.GRAY);
            }
        }
    }
}
```